# How to convert date coming from the db JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, date-format, date-formatting

I need to convert this:

```
2020-10-19T16:30:00+00:00
```

To this:

```
2020-10-30T20:00:00.000Z
```

This data comes from the `db` as a `string`.

What is the right way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it should be 11 days 3.5 hours different?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

const tmpDate = Date.parse(2020-10-19T16:30:00+00:00);

const date = tmpDate.toISOString(); //2020-10-19T16:30:00.000Z